# creating type vector in c++

Tags: c++, type-conversion, rtti

I have several classes that each of them has an ID and the Id is passed to the class as a template parameter:

```
typedef class1<1> baseClass;
typedef class2<2> baseClass;

typedef class<100> baseClass;
```

Now I need a map so if I can associate 1 with Class1 and 2 with Class2 and so on.

How can I create such vector? I am working on a header only library, so it should be a header only definition.

I am looking something that do the same thing that this code would do (if someone can compile it!):

```
std::map<int,Type> getMap()
{
      std::map<int,Type> output;
      output.add(1,class1);
      output.add(2,class2);

      output.add(100,class100);
}
```

The idea is that when I get as input 1, I create a class1 and when I receive 2, I create class2.

Any suggestion is very appreciated.

using this data, then I can write a function like this:

```
void consume(class1 c)
{
    // do something interesting with c
} 
void consume(class2 c)
{
    // do something interesting with c
} 
void consume(class3 c)
{
    // do something interesting with c
} 

void consume(int id,void * buffer)
{
    auto map=getMap();
    auto data= new map[id](buffer); // assuming that this line create a class  based on map, so the map provide the type that it should be created and then this line create that class and pass buffer to it.
     consume(data);
 }
```

Comment: Is it 1 class with different template parameters or different classes?

Comment: You `typedef` multiple classes into one single name? I think you really need to rethink how to present your idea to get us understand the question.

Comment: @SombreroChicken It is a class implementation with different template values which make different type. It means that I can use function overloading with them.

Comment: @ChristianG yes, it needs to create an object based on a parameter. But I can not use a long switch statement as each class and their ID comes from different developers and all will be added to the code as a header files. so I can not write a function with a very long switch statement.

Comment: Your example will not work: auto is evaluated at compile time but you get type information at runtime with the id ...

Comment: @ChristianG I know and for this reason I am looking for a solution that works!

Comment: You need something that will evaluate at compile time to store types. You might check [boost::hana::map](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1map.html) for example.

Comment: Look at the down voted suggestion at the bottom. It does exactly, what you want. It's called Strategy pattern, a behavioural pattern that is meant to mask away from the class with the vector the complexity of the different strategies. That is also the only cpp file, which need to have the includes for the different strategies.

Answer (score 1):

As a sketch:

```
class BaseClass { virtual ~BaseClass() = default; };

template<std::size_t I>
class SubClass : public BaseClass {};

namespace detail {
    template<std::size_t I>
    std::unique_ptr<BaseClass> makeSubClass() { return { new SubClass<I> }; }

    template<std::size_t... Is>
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>(*)> makeFactory(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    { return { makeSubclass<Is>... }; }
}

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>(*)> factory = detail::makeFactory(std::make_index_sequence<100>{});
```

We populate the `vector` by expanding a parameter pack, so we don't have to write out all 100 instantiations by hand. This gives you `Subclass<0>` at `factory[0]`, `Subclass<1>` at `factory[1]`, etc. up to `Subclass<99>` at `factory[99]`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want a map to create different types according to a given number.

If that is so, then the code should look something like this:

```
class Base
{
};

template <int number>
class Type : public Base
{
public:
    Type()
    {
        std::cout << "type is " << number << std::endl;
    }

};

using Type1 = Type<1>;
using Type2 = Type<2>;
using Type3 = Type<3>;

using CreateFunction = std::function<Base*()>;
std::map<int, CreateFunction> creators;

int main()
{       
    creators[1] = []() -> Base* { return new Type1(); };
    creators[2] = []() -> Base* { return new Type2(); };
    creators[3] = []() -> Base* { return new Type3(); };

    std::vector<Base*> vector;
    vector.push_back(creators[1]());
    vector.push_back(creators[2]());
    vector.push_back(creators[3]());

}
```

output:

```
type is 1
type is 2
type is 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only to create object, it would be enough to implement template creator function like:

```
template<int ID>
Base<ID> Create()
{
    return Base<ID>();
}
```

And then use it:

```
auto obj1 = Create<1>();
auto obj2 = Create<2>();
// etc
```

Working example: https://ideone.com/urh7h6

Answer (score 0):

Due to C++ being a statically-typed language, you may choose to either have arbitrary types that do a fixed set of things or have a fixed set of types do arbitrary things, but not both.

Such limitations is embodied by `std::function` and `std::variant`. `std::function` can have arbitrary types call `operator()` with a fixed signature, and `std::variant` can have arbitrary functions visit the fixed set of types.

Since you already said the types may be arbitrary, you may only have a fixed set of things you can do with such a type (e.g. `consume`). The simplest way is to delegate the hard work to `std::function`

```
struct Type
{
    template<typename T>
    Type(T&& t)
      : f{[t = std::forward<T>(t)]() mutable { consume(t); }} {}
    std::function<void()> f;
};

void consume(Type& t)
{
    t.f();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is either the Stategy pattern:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
  A() {}
  virtual void doIt() {};
};

class Aa : public A {
public:
  Aa() {}
  virtual void doIt() {
    std::cout << "do it the Aa way" << std::endl;
  }
};

class Ab : public A {
public:
  Ab() {}
  virtual void doIt() {
    std::cout << "do it the Ab way" << std::endl;
  }
};

class Concrete {
public:
  Concrete(std::string const& type) {
    if (type == ("Aa")) { 
      _a.reset(new Aa());
    } else if (type == "Ab") {
      _a.reset(new Ab());
    }
  }
  void doIt () const {
    _a->doIt();
  }
private:
  std::unique_ptr<A> _a;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<Concrete> vc;
  vc.push_back(Concrete("Aa"));
  vc.push_back(Concrete("Ab"));

  for (auto const& i : vc) {
    i.doIt();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Will output:

```
do it the Aa way
do it the Ab way
```

Comment: What would I give for a down voter, who would actually put down a reason.

Comment: I did. I don't think this answers the question. While the suggestion to use strategy pattern might be right, it feels like a comment at most. Your code is totally unrelated to his code sample, where he has integer constants and template classes specialized for these constants. Your approach would force him to write one hundred of `if - else if` conditions, which is hardly a good solution.

Comment: It's not unrelated. He can just replace the string with an integer. *sigh*